# SQLite: Use subquery result in another subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following table with data

```
id | COL1
=========
1  |  b 
2  |  z 
3  |  b 
4  |  c 
5  |  b 
6  |  a 
7  |  b 
8  |  c 
9  |  a
```

So i know ID of 'z' (ID = 2) in the table and i will call it Z_ID.
I need to retrieve rows between 'a' and 'c' (including 'a' and 'c'). 
It must be first 'a' that comes after Z_ID.
'c' must come after Z_ID and after 'a' that i found previously.

Result that i am seeking is:

```
id | COL1
=========
6  |  a 
7  |  b 
8  |  c
```

My SELECT looks like this

`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id >= (
  SELECT MIN(ID)
  FROM table
  WHERE COL1 = 'a' AND ID > 2
)
AND id <= (
  SELECT MIN(ID)
  FROM table
  WHERE COL1 = 'c'AND ID > 2 and ID > (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM table
    WHERE COL1 = 'a' AND ID > 2
  )
)`

I am getting the result that i want. But i am concerned about performance because i am using same subquery two times. Is there a way to reuse a result from first subquery?
Maybe there is cleaner way to get the result that i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) which will return only once the result of the subquery that you use twice:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT MIN(ID) minid
  FROM tablename
  WHERE COL1 = 'a' AND ID > 2  
)  
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t CROSS JOIN cte c
WHERE t.id >= c.minid
AND t.id <= (
  SELECT MIN(ID)
  FROM tablename
  WHERE COL1 = 'c' and ID > c.minid
)
```

In your 2nd query's `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE COL1 = 'c'AND ID > 2 and ID > (...
```

the condition `AND ID > 2` is not needed because the next condition `and ID > (...` makes sure that `ID` will be greater than `2` so I don't use it either in my code.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgZLxDdXJanEWhPdfhP1Lk/1).
Results:

```
| id  | COL1 |
| --- | ---- |
| 6   | a    |
| 7   | b    |
| 8   | c    |
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was exactly what i was looking for.
P.S. I know that AND ID > 2 was not needed. Only left it there to show that this SELECT was identical to the one used above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when id > min_a_id and col1 = 'c' then id end) over () as min_c_id
      from (select t.*,
                   min(case when col1 = 'a' then id end) over () as min_a_id
            from (select t.*,
                         min(case when col1 = 'z' then id end) over () as z_id
                  from t
                 ) t
            where id > z_id
           ) t
     ) t
where id >= min_a_id and id < min_c_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very neat way of doing it.

Comment: @SecolinkEu . . . Probably the most efficient method as well.

Comment: I tested your answer with other answer. Yes, performance is better with your variant. But your function also returns unwanted z_id, min_a_id and min_c_id columns. Also my third party ORM library did not liked the function for some reason. And lastly when i am not the SQL expert, other function is easier to understand.

Comment: @SecolinkEu . . . Just select the columns that you do want.  The `select *` is a convenience in answer to focus on the important parts of the logic.  As for the ORM, I can't speak to that.  If it doesn't support the best querying logic, then it doesn't sound like a useful tool.

Comment: Well that is the point. Select * allows me not to worry about missing some newly added columns in the future.